# How to show dynamic text on node/add form with Panels (using AJAX)?

Tags: 7, ajax, panels, entities

I am using Panels. There is an entity reference field (project) on a content type. It shows the title of nodes where the user is the creator using the viewreference module.

On the node/add form, is there a way to show a field (body) from the node when the user selects a specific project? I am ok with contexts in panels and views, some some general thoughts might help already quite a lot.

Thanks for any tipps.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you do not need to use panels, just add an [ajax callback](https://www.drupal.org/node/752056) on that form select field, where you add a node's body in the postfix of the field.